# Will Prophet Mohammad PBUH Be Resurrected At The End Of Days

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Will Prophet Mohammad PBUH, be resurrected at the end of days, also will all other prophets of Allah SWT, be resurrected too at the end of days

Answer (score -1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah.

How this came in your mind?
This is first time i saw something like this, it is strange... Can i get some source of how this thought came in your mind?
Anyway, **there is nothing like this mentioned anywhere in islamic scriptures. That one or all prophets will be brought back to life in last days...**
If you have any source for this, let us know of it and we will answer about it inshallah.

### Allah knows best

Comment: "Can i get some source of how this thought came in your mind?" A human can think and ask, he just asked nothing strange in the question and please answer with some references.

Comment: @Nofel there is no reference for something which doesn't exist... So here is the reference, no reference which means no, it aint true.

Comment: I think you've got the question wrong on the day of qiyama everybody would be resurrected as it is the day of ressurection!

Comment: @Sassir, well, yes its possible. I thought he is talking about the days before the qyamah, like the last days. Which we sometime refer to as end days.

Answer (score -1):

Of course he will be resurrected on the Day of Judgement because God Almighty Says:

> ”And the Trumpet will be blown (i.e.  the second blowing) and behold!  From the graves they will come out quickly to their Lord.” (Quran 36:51)

So this means, that also prophet Muhammad will be resurrected.

Abu Hurayrah, narrated that the Messenger of God ﷺ said:

> “I will be the leader of the sons of Adam on the Day of Resurrection, and the first one for whom the grave will be opened, and the first to intercede, and the first whose intercession will be accepted.’”

He will be the first to cross the Sirat bridge over Hell Fire.

So yes, he(pbuh) will be indeed awaked up by God Almighty on the Day of Resurrection.

Comment: Why have I got a downvote?